# HTML inside of PHP block, and HTML form with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am newer to PHP, but I am very good at HTML. I have a two quick questions that I need cleared up. First of all how do I use HTML inside of some PHP? Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<body>
  <h1>
    <?php
      echo 5+5; //Here I want the text to be blue
      echo "Hello World"; //Here I want the text to be red
    ?>
  </h1>
</body>
```

So basically I want to execute HTML code inside of the PHP code. My second question is how do I execute PHP code on a HTML form. An example is below:

```
<body>
  <h1>
    <form method="post">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
      if (The Name Forum > 10) { //If the forum that has name in it is longer then 10 characters
        echo "Your name is a very long one!";
      }
      else {
        echo "Your name is average.";
      }
    ?>
  </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: `if (The Name Forum > 10)` - Use [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: `echo '<font color="red">', 5 + 5, '</font>';`

Comment: If you're *very* good in HTML as you say you are, then you're *very* good with CSS too. Apply the same as you would, but echo it in PHP as an inline style.

Comment: i don't really understand what you mean. do you want to check the length of the field in the form? or you want to print out html results with php

Comment: `echo '<div class="I_blue_it">...</div>';` - `echo '<div class="I_red_it">...</div>';` - *Call me dyslexic* ;)

Comment: You need to learn more about php. Try looking for tutorials on youtube, there are many great ones! Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question you can echo html code! Just do this:

```
<?php
      echo 5+5; //Here I want the text to be blue
      echo "<span style='color:#ff0000;'>Hello World</span>"; //Here I want the text to be red
    ?>
```

The php echo statement basically sends whatever is in the quotes to the browser. This means you can echo just about anything: variables, text, or html code! You can echo just about anything. Here is a w3 schools article that talks about it: [w3 schools article](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp).

To answer your second question I would suggest googling it or looking for videos on youtube. Your code has many problems. Here are the corrections:

For one the form tag is INVALID. Here is the correct way to do it:

Secondly the gather the form data (in this case `WHATEVERFILERECEIVESTHEFORM.php`) try this:

```
$name = $_POST['name']; //your form tag declares that your using post so you must collect all variables in post
```

Then you do this:

```
if(strlen($name) < 10)//if the character length of $name is less than 10...
{
  //do whatever
}
```

You need to learn more about php. Try googling common php terms or search youtube and w3 schools. Do some quick research you should find even better information than on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
  <h1>
    <?php
      echo '<font color="blue">';
      echo 5+5; //Here I want the text to be blue
      echo '</font>';
      echo "<font color='red'>", "Hello World" ,  "</font>"; //Here I want the text to be red
    ?>
  </h1>
</body>
```

---

```
<body>
  <h1>
    <form method="post">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
      if (strlen(The Name Forum) > 10) { //If the forum that has name in it is longer then 10 characters
        echo "Your name is a very long one!";
      }
      else {
        echo "Your name is average.";
      }
    ?>
  </h1>
</body>
```

That's what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

When you echo something in PHP, it automatically turns that into HTML code. But you can simly output HTML code directly. For example:

```
echo '<a href="www.google.com">google</a>';
```

This will output a link to www.google.com.
You can basically output any HTML code, including JavaScript, CSS, Ajax, and much much more...